# How to draw this shape with better accuracy?

Tags: java, graphics2d, shapes

I am using `Graphics2D` to draw shapes e.g. rectangles. However, I have got the code working and it draws rectangles on my GUI, but the accuracy is way off and not the size I drag it to be (the get methods return ints by default). Also it seems like the shape size and the number of shapes is random every time I click on the panel.

```
int a,b,a2,b2;

public void MyPaintMethod(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(a,b,a2,b2);
    g2D.draw(rectangle);    
    repaint();
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // ML
    a = e.getX();
    b = e.getY();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // ML
    a2 = e.getX();
    b2 = e.getY();
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see a screen cap of the image you're getting and also a mockup of what you expect to get. There is little to go on otherwise.

Comment: Why are you not using the Graphics2D.fillRect(x,y,width, height) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rectangle2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) is constructed with (x,y,width,height). You're giving it (x1,y1,x2,y2). Try:

```
Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(a, b, a2-a, b2-b);
```